# react cursor none can not adapt

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I'm usisng react and next.js.
I want to use cursor: none to hide the pointer.
I used cursor: none, but it doesn't hide it.

```
const Home: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [mouseX, setMouseX] = useState(0);
  const [mouseY, setMouseY] = useState(0);
  const Mouse = (e: any) => {
    setMouseX(e.clientX);
    setMouseY(e.clientY);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: mouseY,
          left: mouseX,
          height: '20px',
          width: '20px',
          background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #aed0ee 0%, #00f2fe 100%)',
          cursor: 'none',
        }}
      ></div>
      <div
        style={{ width: '1000px', height: '1000px' }}
        onMouseMove={(e) => Mouse(e)}
      ></div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

In you target element you can specify:

```
style={{
  "&:hover": {
    cursor: "none"
  }
}}
```

Comment: <div
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: mouseY,
          left: mouseX,
          height: '20px',
          width: '20px',
          background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #aed0ee 0%, #00f2fe 100%)',
          cursor: 'none',
          '&:hover': {
            cursor: 'none',
          },
        }}
      ></div>

Comment: Type'{position: "absolute"; top: number; left: number; height: string; width: string; background: string; cursor: "none";'&: hover': {cursor: string;};}' Cannot be assigned to type'CSSProperties'.
  Object literals can only specify known properties. '' &: hover'' does not exist in type'CSSProperties'. ts (2322)